# Filemask using new dojo Uploader

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dojo

I created a DOJO browse button to upload files to the server . The button works fine . However i would like to be able to restrict my file selection to *.jpg files only . In DOJO dojox.form.FileUploader i could use the Filemask attribute to select / mask files to be uploaded to the server . Example :

```
var fileMask = ["Images", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png"]

var uploader = new dojox.form.FileUploader({
    button:dijit.byId("myFakeButton"),
    uploadUrl:uploadUrl,
    fileMask:fileMask
});
```

However dojox.form.FileUploader is now deprecated ( soon to be deprecated ) and replaced by dojo.form.uploader . In this i am unable to find any property that can mimic the filemast capability . I read the [official Dojo Uploader documenation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/uploader/) but it does not mention anything about filemask .

Anyone faced this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

dojox.form.Uploader generated a  DOM Element temporarily to deal with file uploading operation. so we could track the  DOM generated with dojo.aspect like this:

```
var uploader = new Uploader({...}, ...);
aspect.after(uploader._inputs, "push", function(method, args) {
    args[0].accept = "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the type by the `accept` attribute and configure it using the mime type.

```js
dojo.require("dojox.form.Uploader");

var tbl = document.getElementById('hola');
var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
fileInput.type = 'file'; //fallback

fileInput.setAttribute("data-dojo-type", "dojox.form.Uploader");
fileInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/jpeg');
fileInput.setAttribute('data-dojo-props', 'name:"uploadedfile", label:"Select Some Files"');
tbl.appendChild(fileInput);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script src="http://amd.egoworx.com/jsfiddle-dojo-require.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="hola"></div>
```

Comment: Additionally you can set image only filter with `accept="image/*"`

Answer (score 0):

Or override Uploader._createInput
Just add one line:

```
accept : ".xls,.xlsx,.xlsm,.csv" // Just add the line
```

like this

```
_createInput: function(){
alert("_createInput 1");
if(this._inputs.length){
domStyle.set(this.inputNode, {
top:"500px"
});
this._disconnectButton();
this._nameIndex++;
}
alert("_createInput 2");
var name = this._getFileFieldName();
alert("_createInput 3");
// reset focusNode to the inputNode, so when the button is clicked,
// the focus is properly moved to the input element
alert("_createInput 4");
this.focusNode = this.inputNode = domConstruct.create("input", {type:"file", name:name, "aria-labelledby":this.id+"_label",
accept : ".xls,.xlsx,.xlsm,.csv" // Just add the line
}, this.domNode, "first");
alert("_createInput 5");
if(this.supports("multiple") && this.multiple){
domAttr.set(this.inputNode, "multiple", true);
}
alert("_createInput 6");
this._inputs.push(this.inputNode);

alert("_createInput 7");
domStyle.set(this.inputNode, {
position:"absolute",
fontSize:this.inputNodeFontSize+"em",
top:"-3px",
right:"-3px",
opacity:0
});
alert("_createInput 8");
this._connectButton();
alert("_createInput 9");
},
```